# Connection between Android and AWS SageMaker with AWS Lambda

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I set up a connection between Android and AWS Lambda which has the endpoint set to SageMaker. I am using the REST API during the connection, the AWS Cognito plug is set to be accessed without authorization.

I make a connection as described here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/call-an-amazon-sagemaker-model-endpoint-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/

My question is how to send this data:

```json
{"data":"13.49,22.3,86.91,561.0,0.08752,0.07697999999999999,0.047510000000000004,0.033839999999999995,0.1809,0.057179999999999995,0.2338,1.3530000000000002,1.735,20.2,0.004455,0.013819999999999999,0.02095,0.01184,0.01641,0.001956,15.15,31.82,99.0,698.8,0.1162,0.1711,0.2282,0.1282,0.2871,0.06917000000000001"}
```

And how to view the received response later. Anyone know how to do it or where I can find tips on how to do it?

Comment: Are you following an online document from Amazon for this use case?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to use https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/guest_access/q/platform/android. Thanks for the help. Now I have to learn how to send a query and display data received from machine learning. But that's for a different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is your system flow:

1. `POST` some data from your Android device
2. It gets received by API Gateway
3. And continues through to AWS Lambda
4. In AWS Lambda the data is extracted, and passed to Sage Maker

#### Creating a POST using AWS Amplify

To `POST` data form the Android device, follow the [Amplify API (REST) category documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/android).

Specifically, you can do something like:

```kotlin
val options = RestOptions.builder()
    .addPath("/prod/predictbreastcancer")
    .addBody("{\"data\":\"13.49,22.3,86.91,561.0,0.08752,0.07697999999999999,0.047510000000000004,0.033839999999999995,0.1809,0.057179999999999995,0.2338,1.3530000000000002,1.735,20.2,0.004455,0.013819999999999999,0.02095,0.01184,0.01641,0.001956,15.15,31.82,99.0,698.8,0.1162,0.1711,0.2282,0.1282,0.2871,0.06917000000000001\"}".toByteArray())
    .build()

Amplify.API.post(options,
    { Log.i("Demo", "POST response = $it") },
    { Log.e("Demo", "POST failed", it) }
)
```

#### Creating POST body from EditText content

You mentioned you're using an `EditText` widget to gather the input data. I assume a user can enter a comma-separated list of values like `0.44, 6.11`, etc.

To extract it's content and build the POST body, you can do:

```kotlin
val input = findViewById(R.id.input) as EditText
val body = JSONObject()
    .put("data", input.text)
    .toString()
    .replaceAll("\"", "\\\"")
```

#### Displaying response in another Activity

Skimming the blog you referenced, I can't see an example of the response body content. But, here's how you can retrieve response JSON and pass it to a new activity.

```kotlin
Amplify.API.post(options,
    { response ->
        val intent = Intent(this, YourOtherActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("json", response.data.asString())
        runOnUiThread { startActivity(intent) }
    },
    { /* handle error ... */ }
)
```

In `YourOtherActivity`, access the extra data in `onCreate()` like so:

```kotlin
val json = intent.getStringExtra("json")
```

Comment: This is what I know. However, I do not know how to pack the data entered into inputs (EditText) into .addBody and how to display the received response on the screen, but in a new activity.

Comment: Updated to answer your additional questions.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already implementing your answer.

The response I get in logcat is encoded in UTF-8:
 I/MyAmplifyApp: POST succeeded: RestResponse{data=Data{rawBytes=[34, 66, 34]}, code=Code{statusCode=200}}